# Why are my JTextFields not resizing?

Tags: java, jframe, jtextfield

```
JPanel dPanel = new JPanel();
    for (int row = 0; row < xyPairs.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < xyPairs[row].length; col++) {
            xyInput[row][col] = new JTextField();
            xyInput[row][col].setSize(100, 100);
            dPanel.add(xyInput[row][col]);
        }
    }
    this.add(dPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

They are just being displayed as super narrow text fields.

Answer (score 1):

JPanel uses FlowLayout by default and it's using the preferred size of the text fields.

Try providing the textfields with a hint of how large you want them to be...

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
```

Remember, you are working in an environment where the rendering requirements between systems can change, meaning that the amount space the field would like to be displayed properly

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details